# How some parts of activity's store in external class on Android?

Tags: java, android, class, methods, android-activity

Assume that i have a activity class named `MainActivity.java`. But this activity has about 3000 lines code for example.

I want to seperate code parts of this file to an external java file(class) named `NecessaryThings.java`. But if i run my project on emulator it stops itself after this operation.

Is there a way to seperate some lines of this activity?

I wrote mini example for better..

Also what do you think about;

**Using this method is beneficial or harmful in terms of performance?**

### This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //I want to call these lines from NecessaryThings.java
    TextView genderResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.genderText);
    genderResult.setText("Cinsiyet:");
    TextView calorieResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remainCalorie);

    String getGenderSTR = getIntent().getStringExtra("GENDER");
    genderResult.setText(getGenderSTR);

    String calorieResultSTR = getIntent().getStringExtra("CALORIECHOOSED");
    calorieResult.setText(calorieResultSTR);

            /*
              .....
              .....
            */


}
```

---

### Aftet I take above code, then I want to store it in `NecessaryThings.java`

like this..

```
//All necessary imports here. There is no problem about those.

public class NecessaryThings extends Activity {

    public void myPersonalMethod() {
        TextView genderResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.genderText);
        genderResult.setText("Cinsiyet:");
        TextView calorieResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remainCalorie);

        String getGenderSTR = getIntent().getStringExtra("GENDER");
        genderResult.setText(getGenderSTR);

        String calorieResultSTR = getIntent().getStringExtra("CALORIECHOOSED");
        calorieResult.setText(calorieResultSTR);
    }
}
```

### If I rearrange my MainActivity.java It will be like this...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    NecessaryThings showMyMethod = new NecassaryThings();
    showMyMethod.myPersonalMethod();


   /*
    the rest of the codes...
   */
}
```

**But it is not working if I seperate code. Why and How can I do it?**

Comment: @A--C why? What is the logic, i could not understand.

Comment: Since no one touched upon it in their answers: Activities have a (complex) lifecycle and initiation process. If you use the constructor to instantiate your Activity, you have an "incomplete" Activity, and so, you get FCs

Comment: @hakiko : you logic is wrong Activity is not just only java class instead of Create an instance of Activity cerate an separate class for sharing methods between Activities

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK You are right. But if i don't seperate methods, intents etc. my activity's  manageability is reducing. Sometimes I get lost in the codes. Have I advantage/disadvantage if I seperate my activity to other classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends NecessaryThings {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myPersonalMethod();
}
```

NecessaryThings extends Activity so MainActivity no long needs to extend from Activity, it should extend from  NecessaryThings. One thing I need to point out is that super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); will call the onCreate(); from NecessaryThings. Since my  myPersonalMethod(); is from super class, you can just call it.

Comment: YESSS! That is the answer :) First i tried multiple extends then i learned, java does not support multiple extends. Thanks a lot. This is

Comment: Problem has solved, ok. But after I do it, have I advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: It depends. If you have alot of NescessaryThings, then theres not much of desadvantage. You should name it `BaseActivity` this is what others do.

Comment: What happends if I hold only Layout-Related things in external class such as TextView and Button objects? Is it good approach?

Comment: Only if all your extending Activities need those methods. It varies on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

All activities are regular Java classes and you can - of course, have many non-UI classes like `Application`, you can have `helpers` etc. Looking into your question, I would like to tell you that the Activity doesn't have user defined constructor and can be created only indirectly by calling `startActivity` method, but in other aspects it is a common Java class.

Hence, what you'll have to do is, let your `NecessaryThings.java` be a normal class, to which you can pass the context from your `MainActivity` and do all that is required.

Hope this helps.